# Configuring geolambda GDAL error

Tags: gdal, jpeg-2000, lambda

I am trying to make a lambda_function.py works in AWS.

I have a lambda using geolambda v4 and geolambda-python v3 as layers, for running a script in Python that uses sentinel-2 jp2 files.
Python interpret is 3.7

The files (objects) are listed using s3_client.list_objects, so I don't have credentials issues.

However, when running the command:

```
src_tci_ds = gdal.Open('/vsis3/my-bucket/tile/image.jp2')
```

I got this error:

```
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.XML: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.xml: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.IMD: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.imd: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.RPB: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.rpb: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.PVL: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file.pvl: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file_rpc.txt: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file_RPC.TXT: 403
Warning 1: HTTP response code on https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/file_metadata.txt: 403
```

Surely, it must be some configuration I am missing, but what could it be?

The bucket has PUBLIC access at the moment, but that hasn't helped so far.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, 403 errors in Python scripts can be overcome by specifying `User Agents`, which help to make your HTTP requests appear to be coming from a browser. This isn't really a GIS SE question, so I would just search SO for answers, starting here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden